# My render is not showing the object, it shows only a blank grid. Blender 2.90

Tags: rendering

I tried rendering a donut, and a cube, but neither render, only a grid appears.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up/67491

Comment: Hello :). Only a grid appears? Did you press F12 to render your scene, or F11 to view finished renders?